# Javascript how to put a img inside a document table

Tags: javascript

I have this code but I can see the images when I debug.
What´s i am doing wrong? 
Mabe someting when i call the img src?

```
xmlhttp.open("GET", "//site.xml", false);

xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 

document.write("<table border='1'>");
var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("entry");
for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
  { 
    document.write("<tr><td>");

    document.write('<a href="' + x[i].getElementsByTagName("id")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + '"> <img src=' + '"http//google.com/images/logo.gif"' + 'border="0" width="276" height="110" /></a>');
    document.write("</td><td>");



  document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("title")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  document.write("</td></tr>");
  //alert('[1]');
}




//alert('[2]');
document.write("</table>");
```

Comment: What **do** you see? And why in heavens name are you writing HTML using JavaScript. That's just... ugly :/. If I should guess, it's because the GET request is async and your code does not wait for it to return.

Answer (score 0):

You have some issues in your code :

1- First, ajax calls are asynchronous ([W3C Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp)), so your code won't wait until the ajax call is completed to continue the execution. => You have to define a handler function to the onreadystatechange before calling the `send` method.

Example

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
    /*
     * Note this condition (response received and 
     * request status is OK (HTTP 200 code)
     */
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) { 
        //Your code here
       document.write("<table border='1'>");
       var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("entry");
       for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
             { 
               document.write("<tr><td>");
               document.write('<a href="' + x[i].getElementsByTagName("id")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + '"> <img src=' + '"http://google.com/images/logo.gif"' + 'border="0" width="276" height="110" /></a>');
               document.write("</td><td>");
               document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("title")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
               document.write("</td></tr>");
               //alert('[1]');
           }
    }
}
```

2- Your ajax call URL is wrong `//site.xml`. You are trying to access this url `http(s)://site.xml` which has no sense and your `status code` will always be a 404 (HTTP Not found code) so change your url to `/site.xml`

Hope it helps

Comment: The problam is that the I can't see the image <img src=' + '"http//google.com/images/logo.gif"

Comment: Try to be sure that the `xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200` condition is met by adding an `alert('ok')` for example and tell us what you get!

Comment: Yes the code work the problem is that i can show the image <img src=' + '"http//google.com/images/logo.gif"  on the page I dont know why

Comment: You wanted to say that you can't show? There is a location error : `http//google.com/images/logo.gif` instead of `http://google.com/images/logo.gif`